# Infintie sum of imaginary exponential sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've seen many proofs of infinite sums of sines and/or cosines involving the sum 
$\sum (exp(ix))^k$ from k = o or 1 to infinity (or variants on that), and somehow this geometric sum is convergent by the standard formula, $a/1-r$ where $r$ is the common ratio, $exp(ix)$. But that formula only works when the absolute value of the ratio $r$ is *less* than 1. However, isn't the magnitude of $exp(ix)$ always 1 by Euler's formula? I'm confused about this.

Comment: What sort of infinite sum of sines do you have in mind?

Comment: One of the series I remember (given to me by someone) was sum of sin(kx) from k=0 to infinity.

Comment: That series doesn't converge, unless $x$ is chosen so that it's identically zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you've seen sums like
$$ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\sin n}{n}, $$
which converge. The way one shows that this sum converges is by noting that $\frac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing function that goes to $0$, and the partial sums
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^k \sin n$$
are bounded as $k \to \infty$. Then one can apply [Dirichlet's Convergence Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

The key here is not that the partial sums of $\sin n$ converge to some number - they do not. But they are bounded, which one can see from using geometric series on the exponentials, as you mentioned.